# Load new page after content script injection while stopping/ignoring other running scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**My specific problem:**

I have a content script that I inject into a page immediately after the DOM is complete (`"run_at": "document_end"`). After performing a very short task it should load a new website by adjusting `window.location.href` accordingly.

Now I've realized that there is another script (New Relic analytics) running that takes some time to be executed and prevents the new page from loading immediately.

**The more general question:**

a) Is my content script loaded before js scripts that are embedded in the site?

b) If this is the case, is there a way to stop the execution from other/following scripts and immediately load a new page with `window.location.href`?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Use `"run_at": "document_start"`, and MutationObserver inside the content script to watch for the elements being added to the page. Once you get the one you need, redirect location.href

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll have a closer look on the MutationObserver. The problem is that the element the content script is looking for is not always present. Is there a final element I should check for before redirecting?

Comment: Another question:
I guess it doesn't make sense to throw an error (`throw new Error('Random error...')`) after my `window.location.href`as my content script is running in its own sandbox and therefore not effecting the script that is loaded in the header of the page.
Is that right?